# How to select SUM of previous record in group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

### Question

What is the best or most expressive way to write SQL Query that selects

> current row and sum of previous row withing a group

For example, given a table with columns Id, Group, Amount, how to calculate PreviousAmount

Result:

| Id | Group | Amount | PreviousAmount* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | NULL |

#### I've tried:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Group ORDER BY ID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as Prev
FROM Table
```

but it also includes current row

Comment: What do you mean by "sum" and "calculate"? Please show both sample data and expected result.

Comment: group is a reserved word and needs to be enclosed in square brackets if used as a column name.

Comment: RANGE takes duplicates into account, while ROWS don't. In your case ROWS is probably good enough (and it's faster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how to do it :

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as Prev
FROM mytable
```

`ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` means the frame's lower bound is simply infinite.

`1 PRECEDING` represent the row before the current row, it is the higher bound within the partition.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6unPI-0S)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use default range and to substract the  current row amount

```
select *, SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID) - Amount as Prev
from tbl
```

Comment: At least as long as no NULL's are involved.

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would be wise, as the default is `RANGE`.